# Is it possible to associate memory from one struct with another in Rust?

Tags: linked-list, rust, binary-tree, type-punning

I know that in Rust a compiler does not guarantee you to get your struct data in the order you declare them, in order to save memory (I also believe some C code optimizer are doing the same thing). Assume now I have a binary tree and want to convert it to a double linked list. In C I would declare two structs:

```
typedef struct tree{
    void* left_child;
    void* right_child;
    void* data;
}tree_t;
```

for the tree, and:

```
typedef struct list{
    void* before;
    void* after;
    void* data;
}list_t;
```

for the linked list. If I now want to convert the tree to a list I can do this in place, I just associate the memory of the tree with the list struct and change the pointers:

```
tree_t mytree;
/*fill tree*/
list_t *list_p;
list_p = (list_t)&mytree;
/*change pointers accordingly*/
```

But How can I do such a thing in Rust? Is it even possible without using `unsafe` code?
Till now I have my tree:

```
struct TreeNode<'a, T> {
    left_child: BinaryTreeLink<'a, T>,
    right_child: BinaryTreeLink<'a, T>,
    data : &'a T,
}

type BinaryTreeLink<'a, T> = Option<Box<TreeNode<'a, T>>>;
```

and the list would be:

```
struct ListNode<'a, T> {
    before: ListLink<'a, T>,
    after: ListLink<'a, T>,
    data : &'a T,
}

type ListLink<'a, T> = Option<Box<ListNode<'a, T>>>;
```

But how can I now convert them efficiently in place?

Comment: Sounds like a job for [`mem::transmute`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html), which is however, as you suspected, wildly unsafe.

Comment: I'm not exactly familiar with this pattern, could you please expand what you're trying to achieve with this? [`std::mem::transmute`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html) will do what you're attempting to achieve, but it is unsafe, so perhaps providing an explanation of what you're trying to do will potentially reveal a better way of achieving it.

Comment: I am trying to convert a binary tree into a linked list in place, which means without consuming extra memory to build up the linked list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But How can I do such a thing in Rust? Is it even possible without using unsafe code? Till now I have my tree

To do the same thing *directly*, you'll need to use unsafe code. The function `std::mem::transmute` does exactly what you want. The problem is that the layout of a struct in Rust is not guaranteed, so the following would usually be Undefined Behaviour:

```
use std::mem;
let list_link: Option<Box<ListNode<_>>> = unsafe { mem::transmute(tree_node) };
```

However, you can make it safe by forcing the layout of the structs to be predictable, using  the `C` representation:

```
#[repr(C)]
struct TreeNode<'a, T> {
    left_child: BinaryTreeLink<'a, T>,
    right_child: BinaryTreeLink<'a, T>,
    data : &'a T,
}

#[repr(C)]
struct ListNode<'a, T> {
    before: ListLink<'a, T>,
    after: ListLink<'a, T>,
    data : &'a T,
}
```

You will also need to apply `#[repr(C)]` to the definitions of the internal types, `ListLink` and `BinaryTreeLink`.

---

But what about avoiding unsafe code altogether? If you write conversion functions, that *consume* the original data, the optimiser *should* be able to turn it into a no-op because it knows that no other code could be referencing that memory.

```
<'a, T> impl From<ListNode<'a, T>> for TreeNode<'a, T> {
     fn from(other: ListNode<'a, T>) -> ListNode<'a, T>> {
         ListNode {
             before: other.left_child,
             after: other.right_child,
             data: other.data,
         }
     }
}
```

You should definitely benchmark this to make sure, but the optimiser has all the information that it needs to make this into a no-op, and it is very likely that it will.